# Height of terrain Google Map Api v2

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps-v2

Like in tilte, is there any way to get height of the terrain from the google map?
I know that apps like Endomondo using the profile of the area in meters above sea. 
Can i do it in my app using some libaries or api?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I think that what you need is this: [The Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/)

It would have been nice if we could just get that elevation from `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap` but it seems that we are restricted to that 2500 courtesy limit from their api... which is pretty sad.

Answer (score -1):

It's altitude.

On Android Google Maps API V2, **release on May, 2013**, you can get it from the Location object from

```
LocationClient, getLastLocation().getAltitude();
```

On Android Google Maps API V2, **release on Feb, 2013**, you can get it from

```
GoogleMap, getMyLocation().getAltitude();
```

But the tricky thing is the Altitude I got always 0.